# ios , Attach Audio file aac format to Email

Tags: ios, email, avaudioplayer, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i try to send a audio record by file aac (kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) format but the file attached it's doesn't send

*myString = file://localhost/private/var/mobile.......

here is my code

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker =
[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"My Audio File"];  
NSString *fileName = @"Rec.aac";  

NSString *documentsDirectory = myString ;

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/aac"
                 fileName:fileName];
NSString *emailBody = @"AAC format sound file attached.";  
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You're passing in a `file://` URL, which won't be understood by that method. That method expects just a standard file path, i.e. `/private/var/mobile/`.

You could simply use the file path, but if you're only provided with a URL form string, you can create a URL object and use that with NSData.

```
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLwithString:myString];
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL options:0 error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to load file from provided URL %@: %@", myString, error);
}
```